# Does killing Pigs raise Naughtiness as Webber?

Tags: dont-starve

I've just unlocked Webber and have been playing with him for awhile. Not having Spiders attack me is great, especially since I can plant Spider Dens around my base camp as back-up base defense. However, the downside is that Pigs and Bunnymen really don't like me.

While they are a great source of Meat, I'm a little hesitant on whether or not to farm entire Pig villages because of Naughtiness. According to the wiki, Naughtiness increases when you kill a non-hostile mob (such as Bunnies, Birds, and Pigs). However, Pigs and Bunnymen are not "non-hostile" when playing as Webber. In fact, they seem to aggro almost as soon as they see you. So, does killing Pigs/Bunnymen still raise my Naughtiness when playing as Webber? I'd really prefer to not go up against Krampus just yet.

Comment: Naughtiness is a stat assigned to each creature. Only normally peaceful creatures have this stat but I see nothing that suggests it actually matters who attacks first.

Comment: It's also worth noting that bunnymen increase naughtiness, even when killed self-defense by players who have meat in their inventory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a game going as Webber, so I tried this out.  Suitably adorned in football helmet and log suit, I walked up to a pig.  He hit me.  I whacked him with my spear until he died.  I got 3 naughtiness.  (I'm using the Always On Status mod.)

Another pig was nearby, so I walked up and attacked him, and when the battle was over, I got another 3 naughtiness, for a total of 6.

**Killing pigs as Webber raises naughtiness, regardless of who hits first.**

Comment: Of course, the next question is, what happens when spiders Webber controls kill a pig?  I'd guess that you don't get naughtiness from that...but clearly it needs to be tested.

Comment: Seeing how if you kill something with a trap or with fire, you don't get naughtiness because it is the external factor that kills - I would presume this to be so with spiders as well.